# How to find duplicates in 2 columns not 1

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a MySQL database table with two columns that interest me. Individually they can each have duplicates, but they should never have a duplicate of BOTH of them having the same value.

`stone_id` can have duplicates as long as for each `upsharge` title is different, and in reverse. But say for example `stone_id` = 412 and `upcharge_title` = "sapphire" that combination should only occur once.

This is ok:

```
stone_id = 412 upcharge_title = "sapphire"
stone_id = 412 upcharge_title = "ruby"
```

This is NOT ok:

```
stone_id = 412 upcharge_title = "sapphire"
stone_id = 412 upcharge_title = "sapphire"
```

Is there a query that will find duplicates in both fields? And if possible is there a way to set my data-base to not allow that?

I am using MySQL version 4.1.22

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You should set up a composite key between the two fields.  This will require a unique stone_id and upcharge_title for each row.

As far as finding the existing duplicates try this:

```
select   stone_id,
         upcharge_title,
         count(*)
from     your_table
group by stone_id,
         upcharge_title
having   count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that does select them. Could you be so kind as to tell me how to delete duplicates (but leave 1 copy of course) THANK YOU!!

Comment: One way would be to grab all the distinct data and recreate the table.

Comment: @John Isaacks: If there are no other fields with which you could distinguish them (i.e. all fields are duplicates), then you'll have to delete both rows & recreate one. One way would be to copy duplicates into a copy of the table, delete them from the original,& reinsert distinct rows from the copy.

Comment: This does not work on postgres 8.1, could someone give me a hand on that?

Comment: great thanks, does the order that you group by matter?

Comment: And why does adding another column, just for data selection purposes, cause no results to appear, when without the extra column it does appear?

Comment: Nice! ☺ Is there a way to show the `id`s as well? In my case the duplicates are in `first_name` and `last_name` but the `id`s are different. In the query you typed, I can see clearly those repeated ones, but I only see one of the `id`s. How do you do to make it show the other `id`s?

Comment: @PDaddy how would you delete the duplicates if another column was unique? Let's say in this case there is another column called "primary" and based on the ones that have a value of 1 stay and the others you might want to delete. Sorry that I am asking this after 7 years but I encountered this just now and I am in a similar situation.

Comment: @AurelDrejta: I've tried to explain your options [in this db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oevWzhB1jGLbUKaV3oASiC/0).  If this doesn't help, or if it raises more questions, I'd recommend asking a new question.

Answer (score 37):

I found it helpful to add a unqiue index using an "ALTER IGNORE" which removes the duplicates and enforces unique records which sounds like you would like to do. So the syntax would be:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX(`id`, `another_id`, `one_more_id`);
```

This effectively adds the unique constraint meaning you will never have duplicate records and the IGNORE deletes the existing duplicates.

You can read more about eh ALTER IGNORE here: http://mediakey.dk/~cc/mysql-remove-duplicate-entries/

Update: I was informed by @Inquisitive that this may fail in versions of MySql> 5.5 :

> It fails On MySQL > 5.5 and on InnoDB table, and in Percona because of
>   their InnoDB fast index creation feature [http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40344]. In this case
>   first run `set session old_alter_table=1` and then the above command
>   will work fine

**Update - `ALTER IGNORE` Removed In 5.7**

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)

> As of MySQL 5.6.17, the IGNORE clause is deprecated and its use
>   generates a warning. IGNORE is removed in MySQL 5.7.

One of the MySQL dev's give [two alternatives](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/11/06/the-future-of-alter-ignore-table-syntax.html):

- Group by the unique fields and delete as seen above
- Create a new table, add a unique index, use `INSERT IGNORE`, ex:

```
CREATE TABLE duplicate_row_table LIKE regular_row_table;
ALTER TABLE duplicate_row_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX (id, another_id);
INSERT IGNORE INTO duplicate_row_table SELECT * FROM regular_row_table;
DROP TABLE regular_row_table;
RENAME TABLE duplicate_row_table TO regular_row_table;
```

But depending on the size of your table, this may not be practical

Comment: True, but at least for next time you know. I had the same issue and thought it good to share with others

Comment: I was only teasing about it being 3 years late. Really am glad you shared. Hence the plus 1.

Comment: I imagine this removes one of the duplicates arbitrarily so make sure there is not differing data between each row that might be useful to know or keep.

Comment: +1 for the answer even after 2 years late. I accidentally deleted a composite key and this was a life saver. Thank you

Comment: I have tried a few of duplication finder techniques and none of them was this simple and fast. Thank you for sharing this method.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. Although I just ran this using phpMyAdmin and received this warning.

Warning: #1681 'IGNORE' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

Comment: Yes - I'll add a comment stating such

Answer (score 11):

You can find duplicates like this..

```
Select
    stone_id, upcharge_title, count(*)
from 
    particulartable
group by 
    stone_id, upcharge_title
having 
    count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 6):

To find the duplicates:

```
select stone_id, upcharge_title from tablename group by stone_id, upcharge_title having count(*)>1
```

To constrain to avoid this in future, create a composite unique key on these two fields.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you please tell me how to delete all but one of the duplicates. And how do I setup a compisite key in phpmyadmin. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 5):

Incidentally, a composite unique constraint on the table would prevent this from occurring in the first place.

```
ALTER TABLE table
    ADD UNIQUE(stone_id, charge_title)
```

(This is valid T-SQL.  Not sure about MySQL.)

Comment: I think that works but it wont let me do it until I remove the duplicates first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this SO post helped me, but i too wanted to know how to delete and keep one of the rows... here's a PHP solution to delete the duplicate rows and keep one (in my case there were only 2 columns and it is in a function for clearing duplicate category associations)

```
$dupes = $db->query('select *, count(*) as NUM_DUPES from PRODUCT_CATEGORY_PRODUCT group by fkPRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID, fkPRODUCT_ID having count(*) > 1');
if (!is_array($dupes))
    return true;
foreach ($dupes as $dupe) {
    $db->query('delete from PRODUCT_CATEGORY_PRODUCT where fkPRODUCT_ID = ' . $dupe['fkPRODUCT_ID'] . ' and fkPRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID = ' . $dupe['fkPRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID'] . ' limit ' . ($dupe['NUM_DUPES'] - 1);
}
```

the (limit NUM_DUPES - 1) is what preserves the single row...

thanks all

Comment: `ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_name(stone_id, charge_title)` will remove duplicate rows leaving only one unique pair.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller - You saved me hours of dealing with this programmatically in C#. Thank you. - Working - MariaDB 10.5.16

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (ignoring null and blank). Two different email columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   members 
WHERE  email IN (SELECT soemail 
                 FROM   members 
                 WHERE  NOT Isnull(soemail) 
                        AND soemail <> '');
```