# How to find Duplicate Records in a Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, duplicates

I working on an application on ASP.NET C#

I want to view all the duplicated records in a Grid view Control.

I normally use “SqlDataSource” control.

Note that I do not want rows which have one or two things common, I am trying to find the rows which have everything same except the (PK).

I hope you understood the question. Thank ( If you need any other information Please ask me.

Comment: Have you searched this site before asking? This is a duplicate question, many times over.

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20find%20duplicates%20in%20table&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F7580743%2Fsql-server-find-duplicates-in-table&ei=9qUNT5zwBoar-ga9_fydBw&usg=AFQjCNH14a9evyhwwRfKXES3pbN4eRnbow

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find duplicates in 2 columns not 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642656/how-to-find-duplicates-in-2-columns-not-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, COUNT(1)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, column4
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, the simplest way to do this would be:

```
select column1, column2, ... /* all columns except ID */
from myTable
group by column1, column2, ... /* all columns except ID */
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
from
(
    select 
        col1, 
        col2,
        col3,
        row_number() over(partition by Col1, Col2, Col3, ColN order by Col3) rownum
    from yourTable
)a
where rownum > 1
```

This uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, that ranks your records based on duplication (of the columns in the `partition by` clause).  This then selects all of the rows that are duplicates.

Without seeing your exactly table structure, this generic anwer is as specific as I can give.

Answer (score 1):

You can can group and count records in your sql query:

```
select col1, col2, col3, count(1)
from table
group by col1, col2, col3
having count(1) > 1
```

Comment: That will only find a duplicate count, not the actual records that are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, here is another:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2
ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.field2 = t2.field2 AND t1.field3 = t2.field3 ... etc ...
WHERE t1.PKID <> t2.PKID
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you help this is what I was looking for....

```
select ProductID, Date, Category, COUNT(*)from Table1GROUP BY ProductID, Date, Category HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- gets only rows with more than 1 grouping
```