# Laravel whereIn AND whereIn?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, duplicates

So I am trying to display duplicate results based on two fields, they have to both match. I have an `Expense` model and I want to grab only the results where the `date` AND `amount` are the same, and return those results. For example, what I have so far:

```
$results = Expense::where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('amount', function ($q) {
            $q->select('amount')->from('expenses')->groupBy('amount')->havingRaw('count(*) > 1');
        })->whereIn('date', function ($q) {
            $q->select('date')->from('expenses')->groupBy('date')->havingRaw('count(*) > 1');
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

This does show me duplicate results BUT also where ONLY the amount OR date match, but I need both the amount AND the date to match. The below gives me the same results:

```
Expense::whereIn('date', array_column(DB::select('select date from expenses group by date having count(*) > 1'), 'date'))
    ->whereIn('amount', array_column(DB::select('select amount from expenses group by amount having count(*) > 1'), 'amount'))
    ->get());
```

So, for example, in my database I have the following `expenses`:

```
Name: Expense 1
Amount: 500
Date: 2022-04-16

Name: Expense 2
Amount: 500
Date: 2022-04-16

Name: Expense 3
Amount: 500
Date: 2022-04-15
```

The third expense should not be returned but it does get included in the results. Any pointers to get me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you could grouBy two columns. Try `Expense:select('amount','date', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
->groupBy('amount', 'date')
->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
->get();`

Comment: I actually did not think of this and it is not `exactly` what I was looking for BUT it is a good solution and perhaps in the end even works better than what I wanted. So if you can post answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Ok, I can write the answer if it solves your problem. But keep in mind that you will only get the amount and date data, that is, you will not get the id of the duplicate rows, if that is what you are looking for

Comment: True, but they are not explicitly needed. Would be nice to get them as well but if not, no worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not using `whereIn`, as you stated in the question, you also have the possibility to group the rows by two columns.
So, you can tell Eloquent to select the two columns you're interested in and also a `count` aggregate, then group by those two columns and ask for only the ones having `count` greater than `1`.

```
$results = Expense:select('amount','date', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
    ->groupBy('amount', 'date')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
    ->get();
```

Following the example:

Expense 1

- Amount: `500`
- Date: `2022-04-16`

Expense 2

- Amount: `500`
- Date: `2022-04-16`

Expense 3

- Amount: `500`
- Date: `2022-04-15`

The expected results would be:

- Amount: `500`
- Date: `2022-04-16`
- Count: `2`

Comment: Thanks, accepted this because it is the closest to what I need I think. I am going to play around with collection groupBy's later just to check if I can get a better solution for my use case, although I wanted to prevent that because that way I have to get all expenses from the database first and then grouping them etc. But atm I do have a working solution thanks to your answer.

Comment: @Hardist after the comments i was wondering how to get the id of the duplicates.  I'm writing from my phone now, but passing the query from this answer to eloquent might be a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754936/7498116