# MySQL: Find "same" Data

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently in the need to find entrys matching the same pattern in a connection table.

The Table looks like

```
id    job_id   data1 ext_id
--    ------   ----- -----
1     15       1     3  
2     15       2     7
3     1        1     5  
4     1        2     4  
5     5        1     3
6     5        2     7
```

so my basic information is the data of job_id 15

```
id    job_id   data1 ext_id
--    ------   ----- -----
1     15       1     3  
2     15       2     7
```

I want to find job_id 5 because the data in ext_id and data1 is the same as in job 15. the data of job_id 1 differs, so I don't want to find that.
Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: tried different ways to join the table together.. but to be honest I have just no idea on how to select depending of the data. I was thinking about building the sql-query manually after i retrieved the information about which combinations are for job 15 but there must be a more elegant way i hope :)

Comment: Try with job_id=5 in where clause

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
select   *
from     your_table
group by data1,
         ext_id
having   count(*) > 1
```

This post explains it:
[How to find duplicates in 2 columns not 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642656/how-to-find-duplicates-in-2-columns-not-1)

**EDIT**

I believe this should return all rows that have mathcing data1 and ext_id values

```
select * from table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.data1=t2.data1 and t1.ext_id=t2.ext_id
```

Comment: @einars Please tell  me the output

Comment: sadly no. That doesn't really help. I try to find "duplicates" on data for a given id.

Comment: yes, it selects all which are matching. but the important part is that it findes matching the WHOLE dataset.

Comment: pseudo code: select id from table where data like (select * from table where id = 15)