# How to delete one of the duplicates based on another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a follow-up of the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642656/how-to-find-duplicates-in-2-columns-not-1)

Let's say that i have another column called "primary" in the schema presented in the question above so now it would look something like this:

Stones Table:

```
stone_id = 412 upcharge_title = "sapphire" primary = 1
stone_id = 412 upcharge_title = "sapphire" primary = 0
```

I want to delete the rows that are duplicates in the "stone_id" and "upcharge_title" fields and have the value on the "primary" field equal to 0 but leave the other row that has the value of primary equal to 1?

How can i do that with MySQL?

Comment: I apologize for not following those guidelines. Next time I will try my best to be a bit more descriptive and provide better mock-ups to help others answer my questions when asking questions related to SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a self join:

```
delete t1
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on t1.stone_id = t2.stone_id and t1.upcharge_title = t2.upcharge_title 
and t1.primary = 0 and t2.primary = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uD5ktzMb38ic4nWkGd3MPd/1).

Comment: How is this actually working? I can't seem to wrap my head around it

Comment: Every row of the table with primary = 0 is joined to another row with primary = 1 and the same stone_id and upcharge_title (if it exists). So for every such match the row with primary = 0 is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select stone_id, upcharge_title, max(primary) as max_primary
          from t
          group by stone_id, upcharge_title
         ) tt
         using (stone_id, upcharge_title)
    where t.primary = 0 and tt.max_primary = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use subquery approach

```
delete from tbl
where primary != 0 and (stone_id, upcharge_title) = (
  select stone_id, upcharge_title
  from tbl
  group by stone_id, upcharge_title
  having count(*) > 1
)
```